# Conversion from jquery to Dojo

Tags: jquery

If you had to do this..

```
function disableAutoComplete(id) {
    jQuery("#" + id).attr("autocomplete", "off");
}

/* Registers function for SELECT element */

function registerHandler(id, event, handler) {
    switch (event) {
    case "change":
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#" + id).change(handler);
        });
        break;
    case "click":
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#" + id).click(handler);
        });
        break;
    case "keyup":
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#" + id).keyup(handler);
        });
        break;
    case "focus":
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#" + id).focus(handler);
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

with  dojo instead of jquery, how would you do it?

Comment: I don't do this with jQuery. I do this: `function registerHandler(id, event, handler) { jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery("#" + id).bind(event, handler);}); }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a dojo expert, you can also find this solution from documentation:

```
function disableAutoComplete(id) {
    dojo.attr(dojo.byId(id), "autocomplete", "off");
}

function registerHandler(id, event, handler) {
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId(id), "on" + event, handler);
}
```

[dojo.attr()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/attr.html#dojo-attr), [dojo events](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html)

And that's not the jQuery way of doing things. It should be like this:

```
function disableAutoComplete(id) {
    jQuery("#" + id).prop("autocomplete", "off");
}

/* Registers function for SELECT element */

function registerHandler(id, event, handler) {
    jQuery("#" + id).bind(event, handler);
}
```

Comment: Can some one convert the above two methods given in my post to Dojo from Jquery .

Comment: I did it. First example is dojo solution.

Comment: jQuery("#" + id).change(handler);
 Just tell me the alternative of this line in DOJO

Comment: Can anyone please reply to me previous comment . The alternative of this code jQuery("#" + id).change(handler); in Dojo

Comment: @pagisush I already answered that. Check my answer again. The code you're looking for is in the first code block.